# VoIP on wifi not working in sleep mode

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, voip

My calls don't come in, with voip on wifi, when my nexus 5 is in sleep mode. I went into settings to put "always keep wifi on" but no result.

When screen shuts down, my voip app seems to disconnect and even after reopening the phone i have to reactivate the voip app.

Android lollipop was installed the day i got my new phone so i can't tell if it's the new android version. Thinking about returning the phone to google.

I verified all the options in my app and on the phone itself. Does anyone have a solution to this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. **Open** your **Settings**.
2. Select **Wifi** (not the toggle option, but in the blank space). *Note: The following option may be under* ***Networks>More Settings***, *depending on your phone.*
3. Open the **Advanced Settings** after pressing your **menu key**.
4. Activate **Best WiFi Performance** mode.